# Result of meeting with dragon?

Tags: dragons, strategy

When queen Iris is elected (old king dies without children, so new one had to be elected), she decides to eliminate *economic traitors* - because she is resolved to rebuild kingdom.

She knows that there are very deep mining shafts beneath town - and that the last white dragon is in large cave where some of those mine shafts end.

Iris decides to send traitors to dragon. But white dragons are extremely intelligent and very peaceful, excepting mother's protection of children.

So, what may be result of meeting with dragon (if dragon and egg must survive)?

Comment: It seems to me like everything in this question except the final sentence is unrelated filler. Additionally, I don't see how we can answer this at all without knowing a lot about what dragons are like in your world.

Comment: "*Do not meddle in the affairs of Dragons, for you are crunchy and taste good with ketchup!*"

Comment: @Schwern I suggest trying raspberry jam.

Answer (score 1):

> Iris decides to send traitors to dragon.

...to do what? Dragon census? And why are "economic traitors" qualified to do that?

I'm not sure what "economic traitors" are, but they don't sound like violent, menacing people who will just kill a dragon. At worst it sounds like they did some shady business deals rather than try to overthrow the kingdom. Or Iris just decided she didn't like them and trumped up some Stalin-esque charges.

You didn't give a reason for there to be a conflict between the traitors and the dragon, the traitors are traitors to the kingdom, not the dragon. On the dragon side, you said they're intelligent and peaceful, not wild beasts who will attack anyone who enters their territory.

So... nothing happens? Maybe they swap investment tips? The best ways to pile your hoard?

If you want a conflict between peaceful, intelligent dragons and some businessmen, you have to come up with a reason for it. We don't know enough about your world to do that.